# vagrant symlink protocol error inside synced folder using relative path

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, symlink

I am trying to create a vanilla `ubuntu/trusty64` guest box with symbolic links using a relative path on an ubuntu host.

```
> mkdir -p tmp1/tmp2
> mkdir -p tmp1/tmp3
> vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
```

Inside the newly created Vagrantfile add the folder syncing:

```
...
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.synced_folder File.expand_path("~/tmp1"),
                                         "/home/vagrant/tmp1",
                                         :create => true
...
```

Then bring up the box and ssh to it:

```
> vagrant up
> vagrant ssh
```

Then, `cd` to the `tmp2` directory and try to create a symlink to `tmp3`:

```
> cd tmp1/tmp2
> ln -s ../tmp3 test
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘test’: Protocol error
```

Version info:

```
> vagrant version
Vagrant 1.7.4
> vboxmanage --version
5.0.4r102546
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: looks like you're using VirtualBox provider ? might be a limitation of the VirtualBox shared folders as it is working fine from my vmware VM

Comment: @FredericHenri, yes, that's a good point. I am using the VirtualBox provider, and it may be a VB limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue with the homestead environment on Windows 10. In the end it worked by starting the terminal with admin credentials (Run as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Virtualbox 5.0.4 . See [bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14563)

Just to note, this doesn't only affect Mac OSX hosts as the ticket reports. I ran into the same issue with Arch linux as a host. Either revert Virtualbox to version 5.0.2, which seems to work, or wait for the release of Virtualbox 5.0.5, which supposedly fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

virtual box 5.2.6

vagrant 2.0.1

windows 10

same problem (ln: failed to create symbolic link ... Protocol error )
when I ran "composer install" to install drafter-install

(if your homestead is running, vagrant halt firstly)

### my solution is execute cmd as "administrator privilege"

- vagrant up
- vagrant ssh
- cd to my project's dir
- composer install

that's all, and work well for me

Comment: Did you give administrator privilege to the virtualbox.exe or vagrant.exe?